# { "message": "Error : An error occurred: 'str' object does not support item assignment." }

Tags: python, azure-blob-storage, langchain, pinecone

I have a blob storage account where I dropped a single file.
Then I want to add a record on pinecone based on this file using langchain:

```
@app.get("/BlobStorage")
def IndexContainer(storageContainer: str, indexName: str, namespace_name: str):
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function IndexContainer processed a request.')

    try:
        pinecone.init(
            api_key=os.getenv("pineconeapikey"),
            environment=os.getenv("pineconeenvironment")
        )

        connect_str = os.getenv('blobstorageconnectionstring')
        loader = AzureBlobStorageContainerLoader(conn_str=connect_str, container=storageContainer)
        embeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings(deployment=os.getenv("openai_embedding_deployment_name"),
                                        model=os.getenv("openai_embedding_model_name"),
                                        chunk_size=1)

        openai.api_type = "azure"
        openai.api_version =os.getenv("openai_api_version")
        openai.api_base =os.getenv("openai_api_base")
        openai.api_key =os.getenv("openai_api_key")

        documents = loader.load()
        texts = []
        metadatas = []

        for doc in documents:
            texts.append(doc.page_content)
            metadatas.append(doc.metadata['source'])

        docsearch = Pinecone.from_texts(
            texts,
            embeddings,
            index_name=indexName,
            metadatas=metadatas,
            namespace=namespace_name
        )


        return {
            "message":f"File indexed. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully."
        }
    except Exception as e:
        error_message = f"An error occurred: {str(e)}"
        logging.exception(error_message)
        return {
            "message":f"Error : {error_message}."
        }
```

I debugged this code line by line and all variables are setup correctly and the exception is only thrown until the *from_texts* method.

However I get this error:

> An error occurred: 'str' object does not support item assignment.

loader.load is below:

```
[Document(page_content="long content", metadata={'source': 'C:\\Users\\xx\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmpk5cqh4nd/abc/filenameAI sorting_Project Description.docx'})]
```

#### Stack trace

[image]

What am I missing?

I based my code on the unit tests of langchain:

https://github.com/hwchase17/langchain/blob/e27ba9d92bd2cc4ac9ed7439becb2d32816fc89c/tests/integration_tests/vectorstores/test_pinecone.py#L118

If it helps, the Blob Storage Container loader from Langchain is implemented here:

https://github.com/hwchase17/langchain/blob/e27ba9d92bd2cc4ac9ed7439becb2d32816fc89c/langchain/document_loaders/azure_blob_storage_container.py

Comment: Can you add the full stacktrace? What is `loader`? What does `loader.load()` return?

Comment: Out of curiosity did you managed to resolve the [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76605471/6699447)?

Comment: Please show whole traceback - you logged it with logging.exception. With that we'll actually know what line is wrong

Comment: You still have not provided the full traceback!

Comment: I added a screenshot of the watch window in vscode for variable e,

Comment: That is not what we need... The traceback should be printed by `logging.exception`

Comment: not sure how to get it?

Comment: my code is based from: https://github.com/hwchase17/langchain/blob/e27ba9d92bd2cc4ac9ed7439becb2d32816fc89c/tests/integration_tests/vectorstores/test_pinecone.py#L118

Comment: If it helps, the Blob Storage Container loader from Langchain is implemented here: 

https://github.com/hwchase17/langchain/blob/e27ba9d92bd2cc4ac9ed7439becb2d32816fc89c/langchain/document_loaders/azure_blob_storage_container.py

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76620938/edit). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is int the `metadata` variable. Looking at the source code it seems that metadata needs to be a list of dictionaries. You are passing a list of strings instead.

Just fix it by:

```py
        for doc in documents:
            texts.append(doc.page_content)
            metadatas.append(doc.metadata)
```

Comment: that was my first attempt before posting the question here, however the error is different:     '{"code":3,"message":"metadata size is 140376 bytes, which exceeds the limit of 40960 bytes per vector","details":[]}'

Comment: If it helps, the Blob Storage Container loader from Langchain is implemented here: 

https://github.com/hwchase17/langchain/blob/e27ba9d92bd2cc4ac9ed7439becb2d32816fc89c/langchain/document_loaders/azure_blob_storage_container.py